# Call a user defined function/alias with arguments in ZSH shell

Tags: zsh, zshrc, zsh-alias

I am using zsh for my shell and I have the following function defined in my `~/.zshrc` to run custom commands inside my vagrant VM.

```
vt() {
    pushd ~/dev/vvv
    vagrant ssh -c $@
    popd
}
```

So to run the `xdebug_on` command inside my vagrant VM, I can just use the alias `vt xdebug_on`

I want to shorten this further and so I created another alias/function called `vtxon`

```
vtxon() {
    pushd ~/dev/vvv
    vagrant ssh -c xdebug_on
    popd
}
```

which is working, but I want to know if there is a way I can reuse `vt` alias/function `vtxon` instead of recreating everything.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Did you try a trivial `vtxon() { vt xdebug_on }` yet? Should work as long as the called function is known in the scope.

Comment: Damn! you are correct! I don't know why this simple trivial thing escaped my mind. Please post it as an answer so that I can get you some karma :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try a trivial

```
vtxon() {
    vt xdebug_on
}
```

yet? Should work as long as the called function is known in the scope.